# passing 'const QVariant' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have a `struct` like this:

```
struct StorageConfig {
    QString id;
    QString description;
    QVariant value;
};
```

I want to assign the value of a `QLineEdit` to the value of my `StorageConfig.value`:

```
for (int j=0; j<parameters.count(); j++) {
    if (parameters.at(j).id == id) {
        parameters.at(j).value = QVariant(myQLineEdit->text());
        break;
    }
}
```

`parameters` is a `QList<StorageConfig>`

But I got this error:

> passing 'const QVariant' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>
> ```
>             parameters.at(j).value = QVariant(myQLineEdit->text());
>
>                                    ^
> ```

I understand perfectly the issue : `myQLineEdit->text()` return a `const` and I cannot assing a `const` to a `non-const` variable.  That's OK.

But my problem is… I don't know how to solve this.
I can't remove `const` status of `text()` because it's an internal Qt method.
And I don't want to change my `StorageConfig.value` to `const` because I want to be able to modify it later.

I just want to get rid of this `const` on my `QString`.  But I don't know how.
I've tried with `std::remove_const` and by storing `text()` in a temporary `QString` but it didn't work.
So, I'm out of ideas.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `parameters` a *constant* `QList<StorageConfig>`? Or a reference to a *constant* object? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Gues: you are assigning in a const function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `QList::at()` returns `const T &`. Use `QList::operator[]` instead: `parameters[j].value = QVariant(myQLineEdit->text());`.